# If Apple rejects an app in to the Mac App store, when I resubmit, do I need to change the build number?

Tags: macos, mac-app-store

We currently have a build number that matches our version, so we cannot have more than one build number per version. We would need to change this if Apple require different build numbers for submissions of the same version of an app.

If Apple rejects an app in to the Mac App store, when I resubmit, do I need to change the build number?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Then answer is yes, you need a different one. For [Screensaver Ninja](https://Screensaver.Ninja) we were using this schema for build numbers: 001002003 representing version 1.2.3. This limitation made us reconsider.

We considered 001002003004 but that seemed too long and hard to read, so I attempted 001.002.003.004 but then I learned that you build numbers are between one and three period separated integers. We ended up going for 001002003.004 to represent 1.2.3 build 4 (the fifth build with version 1.2.3).